# vim lose colorscheme toggling syntax

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have the following function:

```
function! ToggleSyntax()
    if exists("g:syntax_on")
        syntax off
    else
        syntax enable
    endif
endfunction
```

The problem is that if I toggle syntax in order to enable it again, the colorscheme is reset to `default` instead of mine.
I tried also adding my colorscheme config after the `syntax enable`, but it doesn't work.
The only workaround I have at the moment is to source again `$MYVIMRC`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" You are omitting the part where you explain why you are doing that in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, I want to have a way to toggle syntax if I am unable to read a part of code because of it.